# How to use PHP to scrape this content and only get the lat/long

Tags: php, javascript

Say, I have this code:

```
var i = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var latlng = new GLatLng(33.013489, -117.140167);

map.setCenter(latlng, 9);
map.panTo(latlng);

var i = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var latlng = new GLatLng(32.979286, -117.02623);

map.setCenter(latlng, 9);
map.panTo(latlng);

var i = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var latlng = new GLatLng(32.746319, -117.141449);

map.setCenter(latlng, 9);
map.panTo(latlng);

var i = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
var latlng = new GLatLng(32.758286, -117.125053);

map.setCenter(latlng, 9);
map.panTo(latlng);
```

How do I use PHP to return a list or just the latitudes and longitudes. So anything between `GLatLng()`

So I would end up with an array that looks something like this:

```
32.758286, -117.125053
32.979286, -117.02623
32.746319, -117.141449
32.758286, -117.125053
```

Comment: It's not an html, it's a javascript

Comment: How are you getting that file?  Are you saying you want to parse that Javascript file externally?  Or something else?  Why are you not just updating the javascript to output those points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can do this by first finding the start string you named `GLatLng(`, then finding the end string `)` and take the value between. The repeat as long as you can find the start string.

[Demo:](https://eval.in/44670)

```
$result = [];
$start  = 'GLatLng(';
$offset = 0;
while (false !== $pos = strpos($buffer, $start, $offset))
{
    $offset   = $pos + strlen($start);
    $result[] = substr($buffer, $offset, strpos($buffer, ')', $offset) - $offset);
}
```

Comment: right, i get the concept behind how to do it, i was wondering about the actual php functions to use..... Thanks

Comment: @LatkaGravas: You use string functions for that: http://php.net/book.strings - I added some example code. Alternatively you can use regular expressions but if you're learning I always suggest that you should first know how you would write it your own before using regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_match_all('~
    (?<=\()            (?# starts with opening parentheses )
    (?P<lat>[\d.-]+)   (?# then a digit, dot or dash more than one time )
    \s*,\s*            (?# followed by a comma with any number of spaces around )
    (?P<lng>[\d.-]+)   (?# then another digit, dot or dash more than one time )
    (?=\))             (?# ends with closing parentheses )
~x', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
/* Split the raw input by its newline characters */
$input = explode("\r\n", $rawInput);

$outputStack = array();

foreach ($input as $inputRow)
{
    splitRow = explode("new GLatLng(", $inputRow);
    if (sizeof(splitRow) > 1)
    {
        /* if you can split the row into more than one peice, you know what's going to be in splitRow[1]: your lat, long */
        array_push($output_stack, str_replace(");", "", splitRow[1]));
    }
}
```